# UseCookieAuthentication doesnt redirect to login page asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have the following in my startup class in a dotnetcore web app:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme = "Cookies",
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                LoginPath = "/account/login"
            })
```

I get a 401 unauthorized but do not get redirected to my /account/login page - any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that `ConfigureAuth()` is ever called?

Comment: In Configure method add the     app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=account}/{action=login}/{id?}");
            });

Answer (score 0):

If the version of your cookie middleware is above 1.0.0,please check [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1044)